How to add user details to MS Word doc using mail merge from MS Access query based on network username
I have an MS Word document that I would like to populate with username details, namely; FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo, MobileNo & EmailAddress. I have an MS Access database that has a table called tblUsers with these fields plus a UserName field (FirstName.LastName). I have another table called tblProjects with project information. I have created an MS Access query that combines these 2 tables and has NetUser() as a criteria for the UserName field. NetUser code as follows;
Function NetUser()
Dim objNet
Dim strUser As String
Dim strDomain As String
    Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    strUser = objNet.UserName
    Set objNet = Nothing
NetUser = strUser
End Function

The query lists all projects with same username details against each one. I then try and create a mail merge between word document and this query however the query does not appear in the list of available queries in mail merge wizard window.
When I remove the NetUser() criteria from query, the query will appear in mail merge wizard window however the query is not filtered to only show 1 instance of each project. I have tried substituting the NetUser() with fOSUserName() and have same problem. My database has a separate backend with linked tables. I was thinking that maybe I could create a username table on frontend to store username and then create a query from this but am having difficulty trying to work out how to do this.
Thanks in advance, Matt.

Exactly what difficulty are you having? Username table would have a single record and include that table in query with INNER JOIN.

Seems mail-merge has issues with user defined function or tempvars in query. Try using a make-table query and then use this table as the source for mail-merge.

It has issue with dynamic parameter in query. I tested with criteria simply referencing control on form and that still fails.

By default, Word uses OLE DB to connect to Access data (actually it depends on the backend). To run a User Defined function in Access, you had to use the DDE connection method, but that was deprecated long ago and should not be used even if you can. If you are basically retrieving a single name to plug into your query, you could (a) save your Word document as a .docm with no data source connection, and use Word VBA to get the name then plug that into the SQLStatement in OpenDataSource, or use your own suggestion of repopulating a 1-row table in Access and using a query as your data source.

Or use VBA manipulating QueryDefs to modify query object with static parameter.

Thanks for your responses. I have resolved my problem by creating a username table on frontend and then updating as follows (apologies about code, couldn't work out how to add in code block?)    {Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strUserName As String

strUserName = NetUser()

strSQL = "UPDATE tblUserName SET UserName = '" & strUserName & "' WHERE UserNameID = 1"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub}
